# client workstation unable to access Sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have installed and configured SharePoint 2010 for intranet use and the site collections are accessible from server, however i am unable to access the sites from client computers in the same Local Area Network. I have disabled windows and antivirus firewall. i can ping the server and get reply but i can't figure out why i cant access the SharePoint sites from client computers.

I have also tried to access the site by replacing the name of the computer by the IP Address, in that case the username and password dialog box comes up and when i enter a valid domain account it comes up with the following message.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013 11:29:46 GMT
Connection: close

Comment: The name you used to ping the server, is it the same name setup in SP (alternate access mapping, IIS host header)?

Comment: thanks David for replying, i only have one entry in the alternate Access Mapping and am using the same name in the default zone

Comment: Check out IIS. Do you see one site for your SP site? Or do you see two by any chance? When you access the site successfully from the server, are you using the same name? Any HTTPS configuration?

Comment: There are 6 websites in the IIS, one is the default stopped website(which has a question mark on it) with path to %systemDrive%inetpub%wwwroot, the second is the default sharepoint site with port 80 and it is started having path to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\virtualdirectories\80; the other 4 sites are different web applications with different poret number than 80

Comment: i am using the full url name to access the default site even on the server like: 'http://drmfss-shrpoint/sites/EWDintranet/pages/default.aspx'  I can't access the default site by the server name like 'http://drmfss-shrpoint' However in the Alternate Access Mapping there is only one entry by the server name like 'http://drmfss-shrpoint' in the default zone ..........and there is no HTTPS configuration i've used

Comment: I added a second entry of the local IP address in the alternate access mapping, and i can now able to access the site from client workstation using the IP address